# App force closes when returned back from the second activity to the first, the first activity no more works, has to be restarted again

Tags: android, json, android-activity

I'm designing an application that allows the user to retrieve his data from the server, I'm furnishing this using two different activities, the first one receives the username as a text input and the second one displays the user's data based on the username. I'm using JSON schema for storing and retrieving the data. The app works fine for the first time but when I logout from the second screen using finish() and try to re-enter a new username in the first screen "the app force closes". This has been giving me sleepless nights, want to be overwhelmed with your support.

> 12-04 16:28:35.289: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 64K, 4% free 6893K/7171K, paused 64ms
>   12-04 16:28:35.299: I/dalvikvm-heap(553): Grow heap (frag case) to 7.757MB for 1000016-byte allocation
>   12-04 16:28:35.399: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 5% free 7868K/8199K, paused 16ms+3ms
>   12-04 16:28:35.529: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 5% free 7869K/8199K, paused 31ms
>   12-04 16:28:35.539: I/dalvikvm-heap(553): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.180MB for 443572-byte allocation
>   12-04 16:28:35.589: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 8302K/8647K, paused 3ms+5ms
>   12-04 16:28:35.889: D/gralloc_goldfish(553): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
>   12-04 16:29:16.819: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1079K, 14% free 7509K/8711K, paused 221ms
>   12-04 16:29:16.829: I/dalvikvm-heap(553): Grow heap (frag case) to 8.360MB for 1000016-byte allocation
>   12-04 16:29:16.889: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 2K, 3% free 8483K/8711K, paused 4ms+4ms
>   12-04 16:29:17.229: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1016K, 13% free 7979K/9159K, paused 3ms+11ms
>   12-04 16:29:18.149: E/log_tag(553): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for Alert
>   12-04 16:29:20.949: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 274K, 12% free 8090K/9159K, paused 6ms+5ms
>   12-04 16:29:26.259: E/log_tag(553): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: No value for Alert
>   12-04 16:29:26.859: D/AndroidRuntime(553): Shutting down VM
>   12-04 16:29:26.859: W/dalvikvm(553): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409951f8)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bombil.kustomizer/com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus}: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1955)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus.AddEditText(Menus.java:309)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus.AddInsertView(Menus.java:121)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus.onCreate(Menus.java:88)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
>   12-04 16:29:26.929: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  ... 11 more
>   12-04 16:29:27.009: D/dalvikvm(553): GC_CONCURRENT freed 273K, 10% free 8248K/9159K, paused 4ms+6ms
>   12-04 16:32:56.799: I/Process(553): Sending signal. PID: 553 SIG: 9

Comment: please post your code or error log.

Comment: Please paste your Logcat and related codes, so here we can help.

Comment: Have a look at the logcat above.........

Comment: Apparently, you're trying to access an object in an ArrayList at in your Menus.java file at row 309. You're trying to access the object with the index of 2, but the total ArrayList size is only 2, meaning the highest index would be 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, you're trying to access an object in an ArrayList at in your Menus.java file at line 309. You're trying to access the object with the index of 2, but the total ArrayList size is only 2, meaning the highest index would be 1. This causes an IndexOutOfBounds exception as shown here:

```
    ComponentInfo{com.bombil.kustomizer/com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus}:
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 2

E/AndroidRuntime(553): at com.bombil.kustomizer.Menus.AddEditText(Menus.java:309)
```

Comment: Sorry I can't help you with that, since I don't know exactly what you are trying to do in the first place. It looks like you are telling the app to add your EditText with whatever content is in the ArrayList at index 2, but the highest possible index is 1 (since your total size is 2.). Go through your code again and see how you're handling the situation at line 309 in Menus.java.

Comment: Resolved it..........:),yes the issue was about the index out of bound but actually this happened because I used static variables and tried to change their values at a later part dynamically. Probably the next time I encounter some problem I will have a detailed look at the LogCat file. Thanks a ton @sander.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any objects that are being used by both activities?  I know I saw this issue once with a project.  One of the activities was messing up the HTTPClient object for the other activity.  If you are getting a null exception being thrown try and find the variable.  If it is a shared resource for both activities then just make sure to deal with it in a clean way when you exit the second activity.